# get information from a sql table

Tags: php, html, sql

I have a PHP web page which, in connection with SQL, prints products from the catalog on the screen.
In your opinion, how can I make sure that by opening an article, the PHP file obtains and prints the images of each product based on the choice made by the user?
Thanks to those who will be able to help me.

This is the script that retrieves the values ​​from the server and prints them on the other PHP file.

I would like to add a button that retrieves information only of the product clicked, I don't know if I explain myself

```
<div id="product-grid">
    <div class="txt-heading">
        <div class="txt-heading-label">Prodotti</div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product";
    $product_array = $shoppingCart->getAllProduct($query);
    if (! empty($product_array)) {
        foreach ($product_array as $key => $value) {
            ?>
        <div class="product-item">
        <form method="post"
            action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image">
                <img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>">
                <div class="product-title">
                    <?php echo $product_array[$key]["name"]; ?>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="product-footer">
                <div class="float-right">
                    <input type="text" name="quantity" value="1"
                        size="2" class="input-cart-quantity" /><input type="image"
                        src="image/add-to-cart.png" class="btnAddAction" />
                        <button onclick="myFunction()">Dettagli</button>
                        <script>
function myFunction() {
  window.open("https://www.w3schools.com");
}
</script>

                </div>
                <div class="product-price float-left"><?php echo "$".$product_array[$key]["price"]; ?></div>

            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
</div>
```

---

VIEWPRODUCT.PHP

```
 <?php
    $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_productacqua";
    $product_array = $shoppingCart->getAllProduct($query);
    if (! empty($product_array)) {
        foreach ($product_array as $key => $value) {
            ?>
            <h3> Articolo <strong><?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?></strong></h3>
                </div>
                 <div class="container">
                 <div class="">
                 <div class="product-item" >
        <form method="post"align="left"
            action="index.php?action=add&code=<?php echo $product_array[$key]["code"]; ?>">
            <div class="product-image"align="left">
                <img src="<?php echo $product_array[$key]["image"]; ?>">

            </div>
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If the script looks up the image based on the product ID, why do you need to "make sure" of anything? What does opinion have to do with it, the script does whatever you tell it to do.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didn't explain myself well.
Basically the PHP page prints all the products contained in an SQL table.
All products are visible through a photo, I would like to make sure to add a button that opens a page where it displays all the details (obtaining the information from the server) only of the chosen product.
I have attached the script that retrieves the products from the table, take a look if you like

Comment: Use a link like `<a href="display_product.php?code=<?php echo $value['code'];?>">`

Comment: BTW, in your `foreach` loop you can use `$value` instead of `$product_array[$key]`.

Comment: The link you say to insert it instead of myfunction?

Thanks for the advice, but I would not like to touch something that then I can no longer fix and I should come back here to ask again :D

As for the link you say to insert it instead of js true?

Comment: I didn't know that's what `myFunction` was for. The function needs a parameter like `myFunction(<?php echo $value['code']?>)`

Comment: @AutomactionProgram, why did you just delete [your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68875331/get-a-value-for-each-button-that-is-clicked-html-js)? That is not very considering towards people who spent time answering it...

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the product code as an argument to the function that's run when you click on the image.

```
<button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $value['code'];?>')">Dettagli</button>
```

Then `myFunction()` can use the parameter when it opens the appropriate page for the product.

Comment: Sorry guys I only read now, thanks for your support. Now when I click the button it opens the page but the page does not display the product clicked.

How can I make the PHP page (the one that opens) understand that it has to print the product information that was clicked with the button?
Thanks a lot friends

Comment: `myFunction()` needs to pass the code as a URL parameter, and the page that opens has to use `$_GET['code']` to show the correct product information.

Comment: The page that opens already uses GET in fact it prints in the name the first article of the table that is called.
Unfortunately, however, I would need you to open the clicked article and not the first article in the table.
I insert above the script that prints the product on the page